# How to fix Margin Auto when Floating-Left Elements are involved

Tags: html, css

Have a class for the `page`, a `container` class for rows of div-boxes, and `box` class to style all of the boxes..

The rows of div-boxes need to be centered on the page..

What combination of `width + display + margin` is required (cross-browser)?

The boxes are floating-left, which seems to be the origin of the question..

Current CSS:

```
.page {
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  margin: %;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd want to use `display:inline-block` in your boxes, effectively treating them like text and then set `text-align:center` in your container

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: grey;
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kBqCJ/)**

Comment: well it's good. but not perfect :) there is a small space between the boxes originating from the fact you now treat them as text and between characters there is that little space too.

Answer (score 0):

I made a jsFiddle. Its fixed width. my question is how many .box elements will there be?

if its dynamic then use some javascript to work out the widths of '.box'

http://jsfiddle.net/james_nicholson/4P9s8/10/

```
.page {
  width: 100%;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:auto;
}

.container {
  width: 440px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background:blue;
  min-height:500px;
}

.box {
     float: left;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    margin: 5px;
    display: block;
    height: 100px;

}
```